# Expanding classes using AutoMap

Tags: c#, automapper

I have to import a set of data from one database to another with a somewhat different schema, and I'm considering using AutoMap. I could just write a bunch of SQL scripts, but I already have both databases in EF and I want to learn AutoMap ...

While many of the classes are similar, the problem I'm having is where the structure is really different.  The target models were designed with several more layers of classes. Instead of flattening, I need to expand.

The target classes have the following properties:

```
public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ContactInfo Location { get; set; }
    public List<Policy> Policies { get; set; }
}

public class ContactInfo 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string EMail { get; set; }
    public List<Phone> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }        
}

public class Phone 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }        
}

public class Policy 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public PolicyNumber PolicyNumber { get; set; }
    public List<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}
```

The source tables, however, are relatively flattened.

```
public partial class Account
{
    public string AccountId { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public string PolicyNumber { get; set; }        
}

public partial class Transaction
{
    public int TransactionId { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> EffectiveDate { get; set; }
    public string InsuredName { get; set; }
    public string InsuredAddress { get; set; }
    public string InsuredCity { get; set; }
    public string InsuredState { get; set; }
    public string InsuredZip { get; set; }
    public string InsuredPhone { get; set; }
}
```

I can create the Map, but I don't know how to tell AutoMapper to handle converting the string Policy to a policy object and then add it to the list of Policies.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source.Account, Destination.Account>();
```

Even worse, the source data inexplicitly has the name and address info at the transaction level. Before you tell me that AutoMap might not be the best solution, please understand that these two source tables are 2 out of over 40 tables in this database, and that the others are not nearly as troublesome.

Can I configure AutoMap to convert the string property PolicyNumber to a Policy Object and add it to the Policies List of the target class?

Any suggestions on how I can get the name and address information from the Transaction into a ContactInfo class and add it at the Account level?

Thank you.

Comment: It cannot be done automagically, but you can easily plug in a [Custom Value Resolver](http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Value%20Resolvers) for this. Or you could do it by hand for these two tables while still using AutoMapper for the rest.

Comment: Another question, how many entities are you going to import? Default support for bulk-import in EF is not implemented, so performance could be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Thomas Weller. Custom Value Resolvers handled exactly what I needed.